# why linux accept() ok with a same ip, but error 24 with different ips

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I have a problem with **socket accept** under my **centos 7.6**

It's the code

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <ws2tcpip.h>
#else
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <netdb.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
#endif // _MSC_VER

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <list>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #define NET_ERR_EINTR                        WSAEINTR
    #define NET_ERR_AGAIN                        WSAEWOULDBLOCK
    #define NET_ERR_WOULDBLOCK                   WSAEWOULDBLOCK
    #define NET_ERR_TIMEDOUT                     WSAETIMEDOUT

    #define BAD_SOCKET                           (INVALID_SOCKET)
    #define stupid_close_socket(sock)            ::closesocket(sock)
    #define stupid_net_error()                   (::WSAGetLastError())
#else
    #define NET_ERR_EINTR                        EINTR
    #define NET_ERR_AGAIN                        EAGAIN
    #define NET_ERR_WOULDBLOCK                   EWOULDBLOCK
    #define NET_ERR_TIMEDOUT                     ETIMEDOUT

    #define BAD_SOCKET                           (-1)
    #define stupid_close_socket(sock)            ::close(sock)
    #define stupid_net_error()                   (errno + 0)
#endif // _MSC_VER

#define stupid_is_net_blocking_error()           \
    (                                            \
        NET_ERR_EINTR == stupid_net_error() ||   \
        NET_ERR_AGAIN == stupid_net_error() ||   \
        NET_ERR_WOULDBLOCK == stupid_net_error() \
    )

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    typedef SOCKET                               socket_t;
    typedef int                                  sockaddr_len_t;
    typedef SOCKADDR                             sockaddr_t;
    typedef SOCKADDR_IN                          sockaddr_in_t;
#else
    typedef int                                  socket_t;
    typedef socklen_t                            sockaddr_len_t;
    typedef struct sockaddr                      sockaddr_t;
    typedef struct sockaddr_in                   sockaddr_in_t;
#endif // _MSC_VER

#define RUN_LOG_DBG(fmt, ...)                    fprintf(stdout, fmt "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define RUN_LOG_ERR(fmt, ...)                    fprintf(stderr, fmt "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)

static bool net_switch_init()
{
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    WSADATA wsa_data;
    if (0 != WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa_data))
    {
        RUN_LOG_ERR("WSAStartup failed: %d", stupid_net_error());
        return false;
    }
#else
    if (SIG_ERR == signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN))
    {
        RUN_LOG_ERR("safe_signal failed: %d", stupid_net_error());
        return false;
    }
#endif // _MSC_VER
    return true;
}

static void net_switch_exit()
{
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    if (0 != WSACleanup())
    {
        RUN_LOG_ERR("WSACleanup failed: %d", stupid_net_error());
    }
#else
    if (SIG_ERR == signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL))
    {
        RUN_LOG_ERR("safe_signal failed: %d", stupid_net_error());
    }
#endif // _MSC_VER
}

static bool tcp_socket(socket_t & sock)
{
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (BAD_SOCKET == sock)
    {
        RUN_LOG_ERR("socket failed: %d", stupid_net_error());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

static bool tcp_close(socket_t & sock)
{
    if (BAD_SOCKET != sock)
    {
        if (stupid_close_socket(sock) < 0)
        {
            if (!stupid_is_net_blocking_error())
            {
                RUN_LOG_ERR("close failed: %d", stupid_net_error());
            }
            return false;
        }
        sock = BAD_SOCKET;
    }
    return true;
}

static bool tcp_listen(const char * host, const char * service, socket_t & listener, int backlog = 5)
{
    listener = BAD_SOCKET;

    if (NULL == host || NULL == service)
    {
        RUN_LOG_DBG("tcp_listen failed: NULL");
        return false;
    }

    if (0 == strcmp(host, "127.0.0.1"))
    {
        host = "0.0.0.0";
    }

    struct addrinfo addr_temp;
    memset(&addr_temp, 0x00, sizeof(addr_temp));
    addr_temp.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    addr_temp.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    addr_temp.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    struct addrinfo * addr_info = NULL;
    if (0 != getaddrinfo(host, service, &addr_temp, &addr_info))
    {
        RUN_LOG_ERR("getaddrinfo failed: %d", stupid_net_error());
        return false;
    }

    bool ret = false;
    struct addrinfo * addr_dup = addr_info;

    for ( ; NULL != addr_info; addr_info = addr_info->ai_next)
    {
        socket_t sock = socket(addr_info->ai_family, addr_info->ai_socktype, addr_info->ai_protocol);
        if (BAD_SOCKET == sock)
        {
            RUN_LOG_DBG("socket failed: %d, try again", stupid_net_error());
            continue;
        }

        do
        {
            const int reuse_addr_on = 1;
            const char * reuse_addr_ptr = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&reuse_addr_on);
            if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, reuse_addr_ptr, sizeof(reuse_addr_on)) < 0)
            {
                RUN_LOG_ERR("setsockopt(reuse-addr) failed: %d", stupid_net_error());
                break;
            }

            if (bind(sock, addr_info->ai_addr, static_cast<int>(addr_info->ai_addrlen)) < 0)
            {
                RUN_LOG_ERR("bind failed: %d", stupid_net_error());
                break;
            }

            if (listen(sock, backlog) < 0)
            {
                RUN_LOG_ERR("listen failed: %d", stupid_net_error());
                break;
            }

            ret = true;
        } while (false);

        if (ret)
        {
            listener = sock;
            break;
        }

        tcp_close(sock);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(addr_dup);

    return ret;
}

static bool tcp_accept(socket_t listener, socket_t & accepter, sockaddr_in_t * address = NULL, sockaddr_len_t * addr_len = NULL)
{
    accepter = BAD_SOCKET;

    sockaddr_in_t remote_address;
    memset(&remote_address, 0x00, sizeof(remote_address));
    sockaddr_len_t remote_addr_len = sizeof(remote_address);

    socket_t sock = accept(listener, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_t *>(&remote_address), &remote_addr_len);
    if (BAD_SOCKET == sock)
    {
        if (!stupid_is_net_blocking_error())
        {
            RUN_LOG_ERR("tcp_accept failed: %d", stupid_net_error());
        }
        return false;
    }

    if (NULL != address)
    {
        memcpy(address, &remote_address, sizeof(remote_address));
    }

    if (NULL != addr_len)
    {
        memcpy(addr_len, &remote_addr_len, sizeof(remote_addr_len));
    }

    accepter = sock;

    return true;
}

static bool server_run(const char * host, const char * port)
{
    int listener = -1;
    if (!tcp_listen(host, port, listener))
    {
        return false;
    }

    std::list<int> socket_list;
    while (true)
    {
        socket_t accepter = -1;
        if (tcp_accept(listener, accepter))
        {
            socket_list.push_back(accepter);
            RUN_LOG_DBG("accept socket %d", accepter);
        }
        else
        {
            RUN_LOG_ERR("accept error %d", stupid_net_error());
        }
    }

    tcp_close(listener);

    for (std::list<socket_t>::iterator iter = socket_list.begin(); socket_list.end() != iter; ++iter)
    {
        int accepter = *iter;
        tcp_close(accepter);
    }
    socket_list.clear();

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    const char * host = "0.0.0.0";
    const char * port = "9999";
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("usage: %s [host] <port>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
    else if (2 == argc)
    {
        port = argv[1];
    }
    else
    {
        host = argv[1];
        port = argv[2];
    }

    printf("listen on (%s:%s)\n", host, port);

    if (!net_switch_init())
    {
        return -2;
    }

    server_run(host, port);
    net_switch_exit();

    return 0;
}
```

**I check the system configs, get their contents:**

**ulimit -a**

core file size          (blocks, -c) 0

data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited

scheduling priority             (-e) 0

file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited

pending signals                 (-i) 14968

max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64

max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited

open files                      (-n) 65535

pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8

POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200

real-time priority              (-r) 0

stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192

cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited

max user processes              (-u) 65535

virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited

file locks                      (-x) unlimited

**/etc/sysconfig/selinux** content:

SELINUX=enforcing

SELINUXTYPE=targeted

**/etc/security/limits.conf** content:

* soft nofile 65535

* hard nofile 65535

* soft nproc 65535

* hard nproc 65535

**/etc/security/limits.d/20-nproc.conf** content:

*          soft    nproc     4096

root       soft    nproc     unlimited

**/etc/sysctl.conf** content is empty

**/proc/sys/fs/file-max** content:

3244136

**Now, Let me tell you what happend**

if 1100 tcp clients from a **same** ip (not server ip), the server is work well

but if 1100 tcp clients frome 1100 **different** ips,

the server will **show "accept socket xxx" 900+ times,**

then **show "accept error 24" alway and never stop.**

The problem seems to be the same as the number of files limited, but I see the system configuration information above is normal, and I have reboot the machine many times

**Anyone know what happend? Please show me the way, Thanks!**

Comment: Nit: instead of `memcpy(addr_len, &remote_addr_len, sizeof(remote_addr_len));`, you can just say: `*addr_len = remote_addr_len;`

Comment: Why don't you just call `setrlimit` on process startup and be done with it.

Comment: @selbie ooh, setrlimit, it is helpful, but not work for my question.

Comment: (error 24 is "too many open files")

Comment: @user253751 As described above, there are two things confusing: 1. 'ulimit -s' gets the limit of files is 65535, and the machine has been rebooted; 2. if all clients have the same ip address, the server is work well, but if each client has a different ip address, the server will accept error 24

Comment: @selbie Sorry, the program not work is setrlimit failed for bad arguments, 'ulimit -n 65535' on start script work well, and now setrlimit work well also, Thank you very much!